# Wordpress search query modify query vars

Tags: wordpress, search

A client has requested that I make the characters "S" and "$" interchangeable in the search function, i.e. "Search Query" and "$earch Query" should return identical results.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: How odd, but I'd think just make sure you wrap the search strings (and possibly results) in single quotes, else it would turn into a variable within your string, which in turn would give you unexpected results and errors. You'd have to post some code on what you are trying to do exactly (or tried) to make for  a proper answer methinks.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I haven't made any attempts yet since I'm not really sure where to even begin with this. My first thought was to use `pre_get_posts` and just regex all instances of s to $, then use an 'or' operator to return results for both queries (the original + regex'ed search terms), but I'm not entirely sure how to do this in Wordpress

Comment: I think then what you are looking for is a custom query using add_filter. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work well enough I guess..

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modified_search');
function modified_search($query){
    global $wp_query;
    if($query->is_search){
        global $wpdb;
        $original_query = get_search_query();
        $modified_query = preg_replace("/(s|S)/", "$", $original_query);
        $new_query = "
            SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND (($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$original_query%') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$original_query%') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$modified_query%') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$modified_query%'))
            ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
            LIMIT 0, 10
        ";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($new_query);
        $post_ids = array();
        foreach ($results as $post_id){
            $post_ids[] = $post_id->ID;
        }
        $query->set('post__in', $post_ids);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are ways to improve that, and I'm more than happy to implement suggestions, but this appears to return results using both search terms, so it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change it before WP queries the database:

```
$the_replacements = array(
    '$' => 'S',
);
function modify_search_vars($search_vars) {
    global $the_replacements;
    if (!empty($search_vars['s']) && !empty($the_replacements[$search_vars['s']])) {
        $search_vars['s'] = $the_replacements[$search_vars['s']];
    }
    return $search_vars;
}
add_filter('request', 'modify_search_vars', 99);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. `$search_vars` is not defined anywhere?